# Meaning of "glorious with expectancy"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Mark Twain’s *Life on the Mississippi*, I reached to a sentence which is a little bit confusing to me.

> Once a day a cheap, gaudy packet arrived upward from St. Louis, and another downward from Keokuk. **Before these events, the day was glorious with expectancy**; after them, the day was a dead and empty thing. Not only the boys, but the whole village, felt this.

Does it mean the day was glorious as expected?

Also this sentence:

> Presently a film of dark smoke appears above one of those remote 'points;' instantly a negro drayman, famous for his quick eye and prodigious voice, lifts up the cry, 'S-t-e-a-m-boat a-comin'!' and the scene changes! **The town drunkard stirs**, the clerks wake up, a furious clatter of drays follows, every house and store pours out a human contribution, and all in a twinkling the dead town is alive and moving. Drays, carts, men, boys, all go hurrying from many quarters to a common center, the wharf.

*The town drunkard stirs* means the town like a drunkard stirs?

Comment: In the second one, 'the town drunkard' is a person, and stir in this meaning is to wake up or come to your senses.

Comment: I *think* that the first one means they were expecting such a great day that it was glorious, but I'm not sure without more context.

Comment: **1:**  *glorious with expectation* means that there is some positive expectation that is making [the day] glorious, before whatever events changed that situation.  **2:**  to *stir* is to start to move, the person that starts moving is that drunk guy from this town, similar to the drunk guy that every small town seems to have who is a shiftless and jobless, who passes out late at night and sleeps it off the next day well past breakfast.

Comment: 'Glorious with expectation' is obviously a transferred usage (days don't expect things and can only be 'glorious with expectation' if there are humans around doing the expecting). There was a great expectation among the people present that wonderful things were going to happen that day. As others have said, even the expectation gave rise to a wonderful feeling.

Comment: "Glorious with expectancy" means they were all anticipating the delivery of the packets from upstream or downstream--mail or goods or both.  After their arrival, there is nothing left to anticipate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*'The day was glorious with expectancy'* means that the day was the sort which felt full of a positive kind of anticipation.

*'The town drunkard stirs'* just means that the town's drunkard (probably the one with a town-wide reputation for being drunk) gets moving from a state of inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence means that everyone was so filled with expectation that the atmosphere seemed glorious. For example, a war might be about to end.  Glorious: marked by great beauty or splendor. MW

In the second sentence, which I imagine is part of the same text as the first, the reader is transported to a less buoyant part of the town where a drunk is awakening. The writer is contrasting the high and low spirits of the town.